# Divs overlapping when screen size is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This may seem a simple question, but i'm using a verity of divs that upon mouse over a css transition brings up another div. See link for demo http://www.minimit.com/demos/3d-flip-animations-css-orizzontal.

It works fine in col-md-3 (full screen) soon as the screen size is reduced to col-sm-12 my divs overlap. If anyone has any free time to see what i'm doing wrong that would be great. Thanks in advance :-)

My messy code...

#### HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="thumbnail-wrap">
        <!-- thumbnail 1 -->

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-0">
                    <div class="content-0">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src="img/thumbnails/1.jpg"
                        style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item-1">
                    <div class="content-1">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src=
                        "img/thumbnails/thumb1-bk.png" style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- thumbnail 2 -->

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-0">
                    <div class="content-0">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src="img/thumbnails/1.jpg"
                        style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item-1">
                    <div class="content-1">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src=
                        "img/thumbnails/thumb1-bk.png" style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- thumbnail 3 -->

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-0">
                    <div class="content-0">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src="img/thumbnails/1.jpg"
                        style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item-1">
                    <div class="content-1">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src=
                        "img/thumbnails/thumb1-bk.png" style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- thumbnail 4 -->

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-0">
                    <div class="content-0">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src="img/thumbnails/1.jpg"
                        style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item-1">
                    <div class="content-1">
                        <img alt="thumbnail" src=
                        "img/thumbnails/thumb1-bk.png" style="width:100%;">

                        <h1><a class="btn btn-default" href=
                        "ground-works.html">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!---Thumbnail Wrap==-->
</div><!---Thumnail Row==-->
```

#### CSS

```
.item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.item-0,
.item-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #ededed;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #f4f4f4), color-stop(100%, #ededed));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 0%, #ededed 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 0%, #ededed 100%);
}
.item:hover .item-0,
.item:hover .item-1 {
    border: 1px solid #afafaf;
}
/* content styles */

.item-0,
.item-1 {
    display: table;
}
.content-0,
.content-1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.content-0:before {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #747474;
}
.content-1:before {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #747474;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I'd start by removing the `position:absolute`...that's likely to be the start of your issues. There's no reason for it in a responsive site unless it's for very *specific* effects.

Comment: Hi Djave, thanks for the quick reply. I tried removing position:absolute but when I perform the mouse over transition the second div moves below the original. Think I might have to revise my layout.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after 4 hours and 2 pints of larger and a pack of biscuits I've sorted it. I had to add a  wrap around my thumbnail. Then I applied `{position:relative;}` with `{display:inline-block;}`. I am relatively new at this but it worked, my divs display underneath each other for responsive @media queries. Weigh in if im talking nonsense.

```
     <div class="row">

           <!-- thumbnail 1 -->

     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
     <div class="thumbnail-wrap">
                  <div class="item">
                <div class="item-0">
                <div class="content-0"><a href="ground-works.html"> <img src="img/thumbnails/1.jpg" alt="thumbnail"/></a><h1><a href="" class="btn btn-default" role="button" style="color:#308ac6;">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1></div>
                </div>
                <div class="item-1">
                <div class="content-1"><a href="ground-works.html"><img src="img/thumbnails/thumb1-bk.png" alt="thumbnail" style="width:100%;"/></a><h1><a href="ground-works.html" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Ground Works &rarr;</a></h1></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       </div>
       </div>

                                <!--- CSS Code--->

      .thumbnail-wrap {
           padding: 20px;
           position: relative;
           width: 100%;
           height: 500px;
           background: #fff;
           display:inline-block;
           border: none;
           overflow: visible;}
```